# How to add squeezeback ad in a MediaLive HLS stream output?

Tags: aws-media-live, aws-elemental, aws-mediaservices

I'm using AWS MediaLive to build and deliver HLS stream of a video file stored in S3. I would like to know how to include squeezeback ads in this HLS stream playout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post.  AWS Elemental MediaLive does not do DVE effects;  it cannot do squeezebacks.  MediaLive does have a keying layer, which enables moving graphics overlays onto the channel output. This would enable you to put up an LBAR animated graphic, but it would cover a region of the video. If you want a true video squeezeback, this would need to be done upstream of MediaLive.

More information on the motion graphics overlay keying can be found at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/feature-mgi.html